# Selenium click is not working after upgrading to ios14 and safari14

Tags: python, selenium, safari, ios14, safaridriver

I have a setup of macOS Catalina with an iPad on iPadOS14/safari14. I have also upgraded both safari and safaridriver on the attached mac. Selenium fails to click and send a text to ios safari and does not even return an error at that point.
Below is the sample code I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

IOS_BASE_CAPS = {
    'platformName': 'iOS',
    'browserName': 'safari'
}
browser = webdriver.Safari(desired_capabilities=IOS_BASE_CAPS)

browser.implicitly_wait(5)

browser.get("http://example.com/")
search_input = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Sign in')]").click()

browser.quit()
```

This used to work on ios13/safari 13 setup but not anymore. Is there any bug in safaridriver/safari or am I doing something wrong here?